# Increment a entry in an sql table via asp.net by 1

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have a database containing usernames and "points".  I need to increment the "points" at will.  I have the table connected to a sqldatasource.

Here is my current code:

```
    With Users
        .UpdateCommand = "UPDATE Users SET points = points + 1"
        .Update()
    End With
```

This works great, except, instead of just changing the entry with the username specified by a QueryString, it changes all of the entries and adds one.

The sqldatasource has the following select command:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE ([username] = @username)"
```

This command makes it so that only entries with the querystring specified username are displayed.  This is really my first attempt at SQL.  Any ideas or solutions would be appreciated.

**--EDIT--**

Thanks for the help Oded, here is my final solution that **worked** :)

```
With Users
     .UpdateParameters.Add(New Parameter("username", System.Data.DbType.String, My.Request.QueryString("username")))
     .UpdateCommand = "UPDATE Users SET points = points + 1 WHERE ([username] = @username)"
     .Update()
End With
```

Comment: I don't see a WHERE on your command, so how is it supposed to know what it has got to update? Even though the SelectCommand specifies the username, the Update command doesn't.

Comment: Yep, that is why I was asking, this is really my first time using actual SQL commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify that only that user row should be updated:

```
.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE Users SET points = points + 1 WHERE ([username] = @username)"
```

When a `WHERE` clause is not specified, the `UPDATE` will apply to all existing rows, as you have seen.

---

Edit:

This is an example of how to add a username parameter:

```
.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40, "The User Name");
```

Comment: It now throws this exception:  'Must declare the scalar variable "@username".'

Comment: @DalexL - You need to pass in the username as a parameter, in the same way this is done for the `SelectCommand`.

Comment: Can you give a quick example of something like that?  Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: Never mind, I managed to find a way.  It took a while but this seems to work:  With Users
            .UpdateParameters.Add(New Parameter("username", System.Data.DbType.String, My.Request.QueryString("username")))
            .UpdateCommand = "UPDATE Users SET points = points + 1 WHERE ([username] = @username)"
            .Update()
        End With

Comment: That didn't post well, just take a look in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Add a where clause to your UpdateCommand:

```
 UpdateCommand = "UPDATE Users SET points = points + 1 WHERE ([username] = @username)"
```

Comment: You answered the question first but Oded down there explained it a little bit more.  Here is a vote.  :)